# Setting custom php include path in .htaccess on mac os x

Tags: php, .htaccess, macos, include-path

in

```
/Users/username/Sites/somesite/.htaccess
```

I have

```
AllowOverride All
php_value include_path ".:/Users/username/Sites/somesite/inludesFolder:/usr/lib/php"
```

I have also modified

```
/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

to

```
AllowOverride All
```

and restarted websharing, but it's not finding the additional include path. I'd like to avoid modifying the php.ini or setting this additional include path with the PHP

Answer (score 1):

The `AllowOverride` within the `.htaccess` file itself isn't legal like that, and might be causing an error that stops further processing. Since the point of `AllowOverride` is to restrict what `.htaccess` files can do, it isn't usually useful within an `.htaccess` file. Try taking it out and see if it works.

Also, rather than modify `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`, Mac OS X's configuration is set up so that you drop a file in `/etc/apache2/users` to configure your own directory. Files in there will persist across system updates and even upgrades!

For example, on my system, the file `/etc/apache2/mark' is:

```
<Directory "/Users/mark/Sites/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: I moved those configurations as you suggested but it still didn't pick up the .htaccess configuration. I only get the extra include path if I alter php.ini